# HTTPS web request failing

Tags: c#, .net, http, https

When I run the program contained below the first HTTPS request succeeds, but the second request fails.  Both url's are valid and both can be accessed successfully in a browser.  Any suggestions as to what needs to be done to access the second url successfully?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var content = "";
        bool status;
        var url1 = "https://mail.google.com";
        var url2 = "https://my.ooma.com";
        status = DoHttpRequest(url1, out content);
        OutputStatus(url1, status, content);
        status = DoHttpRequest(url2, out content);
        OutputStatus(url2, status, content);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void OutputStatus(string url, bool status, string content)
    {
        if (status) Console.WriteLine("Url={0}, Status=Success, content length = {1}", url, content.Length);
        else Console.WriteLine("Url={0}, Status=Fail, ErrorMessage={1}", url, content);
    }

    private static bool DoHttpRequest(string url, out string content)
    {
        content = "";
        var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
        try
        {
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.CookieContainer = null;
            request.Timeout = 25000; // 25 seconds
            var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
            var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            return true;
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            content = ex.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: What error/exception are you getting?

Comment: What is the exception you are getting? Is the SSL certificate *valid* and not expired for the https://my.ooma.com site? If it is valid, is the URL the proper link? When I access it I get presented with a login on a different URL.

Comment: @bryanmac when I run the program the second request times out and generates an exception with the message "The operation has timed out"

Comment: @atconway how ould I determine if the SSL certificate is valid for the my.ooma.com site?  When I access the url in the browser it works correctly and yes it does do a redirect to the login page.

Comment: Depends on the browser, but I just checked it and the Verisign SSL cert for *.ooma.com is good until 12/21/14 so that should not be the issue. You are doing a GET on that URL and it is timing out. What exactly are  your trying to get from the WebRequest from that URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Historically, most problems of this description that I've seen occur when you forget to call .Close() on the object returned from GetResponseStream(). The problem exists because when you forget to close the first request, the second request deadlocks waiting for a free connection.

Typically this hang happens on the 3rd request, not the second.

**Update**: Looking at your repro, this has nothing to do with the order of the requests. You're hitting a problem because this site is sending a TLS Warning at the beginning of the HTTPS handshake, and .NET will timeout when that occurs. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2012/03/29/https-request-hangs-.net-application-connection-on-tls-server-name-indicator-warning.aspx. The problem only repros on Windows Vista and later, because the warning is related to a TLS extension that doesn't exist in the HTTPS stack on WinXP.

Comment: Eric, the problem still occurs when there is only one request in the program to https://my.ooma.com.  I had the two requests in the example program just to show that other https requests were succeeding.  Also, as I have communicated to you via email, Fiddler also fails when sending the request to https://my.ooma.com.

Comment: Eric, thanks very much for your help.  Your support of Fiddler and related issues has always been very good!

Answer (score 1):

Increse your request TimeOut.

```
request.Timeout = 60000; //60 second.
```

May be your network connection is a bit slow. I run with 25 seconds, okay. (*Yeah, the second url is a bit longer to get response, than the first one.*)

Comment: I increased request.Timeout to 90000 (90 seconds) and the 2nd request still times out.  When I access the same url through the browser the response time is less than one second.  Are you saying that you ran the program and were able to successfully complete the 2nd request?

Comment: It's very weird that it runs successfully for you and not for me.  I have tried running the program on five different computers at three different locations and it fails on the 2nd request every time.