# c# can't write POST data to https request

Tags: c#, winforms, https, proxy

Issue is absolutely strange, but I appreciate any suggestions.
Application works using 3 threads and sends POST https requests. The thing that when I'm using internal proxy (Fiddler2) then all 3 requests are sent successfully. When I'm not using internal proxy then 2 requests are sent and the last request (depending on what thread is got to the request faster) is failed with "Timeout" exception. It just can't write POST data. Here is the example of request (which is sent 3 times in separate threads):

```
 //some data before request
 byte[] byteArray3 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post_data_final3);
 HttpWebRequest request3 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(site_URI);
 WebHeaderCollection NewHeaders3 = request3.Headers;
 request3.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
 request3.Method = "POST";
 request3.Timeout = 60000;
 //some headers info here
 try
 {
     using (Stream os3 = request3.GetRequestStream())
     {
          os3.Write(byteArray3, 0, byteArray3.Length);
     }
 }
 catch (WebException ex33)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(ex33);
     Console.WriteLine(ex33.Status);
 }
 try
 {
     HttpWebResponse response3 = (HttpWebResponse)request3.GetResponse();
     //response handling..
 }
 catch (Exception e) {//catching exception}
```

In case 1 (with using Fiddler2) all 3 requests as example above worked well.
In case 2 (without using local proxy) 2 requests done well and the latest one throws exception on stage:

```
 try
 {
      using (Stream os3 = request3.GetRequestStream())
      {
           os3.Write(byteArray3, 0, byteArray3.Length);
      }
 }
 catch (WebException ex33)
 {
      Console.WriteLine(ex33);
      Console.WriteLine(ex33.Status);
 }
```

Note that multithreading and locking is implemented OK, so issue somewhere in Proxy and/or https protocol using.
I can use local proxy every time, but I don't want to. Thanks!

UPDATED: solution found. Closing all responses on end stage becomes working:

```
try
{
     HttpWebResponse response3 = (HttpWebResponse)request3.GetResponse();
     //response handling..
}
catch (Exception e) {//catching exception}
finally { response3.Close(); }
```

Comment: Try testing by adding a manual delay between each POST when not using the proxy. If that works then it is almost certainly a server side issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [HTTPS web request failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900869/https-web-request-failing?rq=1)

> Historically, most problems of this description that I've seen occur
>   when you forget to call .Close() on the object returned from
>   GetResponseStream(). The problem exists because when you forget to
>   close the first request, the second request deadlocks waiting for a
>   free connection.
>
> Typically this hang happens on the 3rd request, not the second.
>
> Update: Looking at your repro, this has nothing to do with the order
>   of the requests. You're hitting a problem because this site is sending
>   a TLS Warning at the beginning of the HTTPS handshake, and .NET will
>   timeout when that occurs. See
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fiddler/archive/2012/03/29/https-request-hangs-.net-application-connection-on-tls-server-name-indicator-warning.aspx.
>   The problem only repros on Windows Vista and later, because the
>   warning is related to a TLS extension that doesn't exist in the HTTPS
>   stack on WinXP.

But the thing how Fiddler2 handles this and make this works is still a magic to me.