# Closing response from HTTPS POST request with exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, https

As it is shown in my previous question about sending HTTPS POST request in multithreading [c# can't write POST data to https request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306326/c-sharp-cant-write-post-data-to-https-request/20311497), I'd like to be sure that responses are closed if exception is caught during HTTPS POST request. Here is the code snippet:

```
public void request_3()
{
     byte[] byteArray3 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post_data_final3);
     Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " " + "request_2 started");
     HttpWebRequest request3 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(site_URI);
     WebHeaderCollection NewHeaders3 = request3.Headers;
     request3.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
     request3.Method = "POST";
     //headers info
     request3.Timeout = 60000;
     request3.ContentLength = byteArray3.Length;
     try
     {
         using (Stream os3 = request3.GetRequestStream())
         {
             os3.Write(byteArray3, 0, byteArray3.Length);
         }
     }
     catch (WebException ex33)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(ex33);
         Console.WriteLine(ex33.Status);
     }
     try
     {
         HttpWebResponse response3 = (HttpWebResponse)request3.GetResponse();
         //response handling
         response3.Close();
     }
     catch (WebException wex3)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(wex3);
         Console.WriteLine(wex3.Status);
     }
}
```

The question here is what if I get an exception during the response so the following code will be used:

```
catch (WebException wex3)
         {
             Console.WriteLine(wex3);
             Console.WriteLine(wex3.Status);
         }
```

Shall I close the response within "Catch" block like

```
response3.Close();
```

Or

```
wex3.Response.Close();
```

To prevent 3rd response freezing if 2 responses got exception? Or does it mean that if I got an exception response is automatically closed?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `finally` to ensure the response is closed regardless of what happens in the try/catch:

```
HttpWebResponse response3 = (HttpWebResponse)request3.GetResponse();
try
{
    // response handling
}
catch (WebException wex3)
{
    Console.WriteLine(wex3);
    Console.WriteLine(wex3.Status);
}
finally
{
     response3.Close();
}
```

Or, better still, `HttpWebResponse` implements `IDisposable`, meaning you can let it take care of itself:

```
using (HttpWebResponse response3 = (HttpWebResponse)request3.GetResponse())
{
    try
    {
        // response handling
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine(wex3);
        Console.WriteLine(wex3.Status);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 `using{}` is Syntactic sugar for `try - finally`.

Comment: @SudhakarTillapudi Not necessarily - they're equivalent presuming all you do in your finally block is call `Dispose`. They will serve the same purpose here but aren't strictly speaking equivalent.

Comment: @Ant P - the only thing I'm concerning of is moving `HttpWebResponse response3 = (HttpWebResponse)request3.GetResponse();` out of `try` block - all 4xx and 5xx errors will throw an unhandled exception then.

Comment: Put the `using` inside the `try` instead.